# Header Section for Stereo .Wav Creation

Tags: c#, wav, audio-streaming

Hello trying to code correct specs for stereo .wav file creation header. Mono file creation works just fine, while attempt to write stereo seems to truncate in half. Pretty sure it's in header section. Both examples (mono and stereo) exhibited below. Any insight is most appreciated.

Mono header - this code is fine

```
    FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(oPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsOut);
        fsOut.Position = 0;
        bw.Write(new char[4] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(length));
        bw.Write(new char[8] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });
        bw.Write((int)16);
        bw.Write((short)1);
        bw.Write((short)1);
        bw.Write(samplerate);
        bw.Write((int)(samplerate * ((BitsPerSample * 1) / 8)));
        bw.Write((short)((BitsPerSample * 1) / 8));
        bw.Write(BitsPerSample);
        bw.Write(new char[4] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(DataLength));
```

Stereo - this only scribes half the length of mono

```
            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(oPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsOut);
        fsOut.Position = 0;
        bw.Write(new char[4] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(length));
        bw.Write(new char[8] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });
        bw.Write((int)16);
        bw.Write((short)1);
        bw.Write((short)2);
        bw.Write(samplerate);
        bw.Write((int)(samplerate * ((BitsPerSample * 2) / 8)));
        bw.Write((short)((BitsPerSample * 2) / 8));
        bw.Write(BitsPerSample);
        bw.Write(new char[4] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
        bw.Write(Convert.ToInt32(DataLength));
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue lies with the sinewaves I'm writing in the body, not the header.